# JOGL Exception- Can't find gluegen- rt in java.library.path

Tags: eclipse, exception, jar, path, jogl

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no gluegen-rt in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1860)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:845)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1084)
    at com.jogamp.gluegen.runtime.NativeLibLoader.loadLibraryInternal(NativeLibLoader.java:102)
    at com.jogamp.gluegen.runtime.NativeLibLoader.access$000(NativeLibLoader.java:51)
    at com.jogamp.gluegen.runtime.NativeLibLoader$1.run(NativeLibLoader.java:70)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.jogamp.gluegen.runtime.NativeLibLoader.loadGlueGenRT(NativeLibLoader.java:68)
    at com.jogamp.common.jvm.JVMUtil.(JVMUtil.java:56)
    at javax.media.opengl.GLProfile.(GLProfile.java:1051)
    at HelloWorld.main(HelloWorld.java:14)

So i get this lovely exception everytime I try to run a tutorial JOGL file. I have desperately tried everything I could. Adding all possible libraries for jogl and gluegen including:

jogl.jar
jogl.all.jar
jogl natives
gluegen natives
gluegen and jogle natives for macosx

Everything, and it says that there is no gluegen library though there obviously is. -.- I read somewhere about jnilib files and tried putting them into the folders with the jar files, but still no luck.

I am using Eclipse, by the way.

Comment: Sorry but putting the JARs containing the native libraries into the same directory than the JARs containing the Java libraries for both JOGL and GlueGen works very well, I tested under Mac OS X 10.6.8 too. However, you need gluegen-rt JARs, not gluegen, maybe you did this mistake.

Answer (score 0):

The OS has to be told where to find the gluegen-rt native library when it tries to run the application, which you can do by editing the "run configuration" in Eclipse to set the appropriate environment variable. I develop on Linux, and for me the steps are

- right-click on the main class in the project explorer
- select Run As -> Run Configurations...
- select the Environment tab
- click "New..."
- enter Name: `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and Value: `/usr/lib64/jogl:/usr/lib64/gluegen`
- click "OK", "Apply", "Run"

On Mac OSX you will probably have to use `DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH` or `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` instead of `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, and the location of the JOGL and Gluegen libraries will be different. These are the directories containing the native libraries, with names ending in `.so` on Linux and I believe `.jnilib` on Mac OSX.

Comment: This isn't the best practice with JOGL 2: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25136112/458157 Rather put the JARs containing the native libraries into the same directory than the JARs containing the Java libraries and it will work without having to modify the library path which is a lot less error prone especially for newbies.